# How to make bullet hit target and display either target was hit or missed?

Tags: python

So for this project, I have to make a bullet hit a target. 
    The bullet is shot using degrees to hit the target. 
    I made the bullet be able to shoot as well as a target being randomly created. 
    However, everytime I shoot the bullet, it simply just asks to enter another degree 
    to shoot a bullet. I am not sure what im missing in order to make the bullet recognize 
    the for loop and if statements near the end of the code. It seems it just ignores it. The 
    bullet also just shoots past the target. I need to make it so it 
    basically creates a right angle with bullet, degree, and target. I thought 
    i did that but obviously something is missing.
    Also, the choice=simple.dialog has no effect either and idk why.
    Thanks for any help!

```
from tkinter import*
import time
import math
import random

master = Tk()
cw= 1000
ch=650
w = Canvas(master, width=cw, height=ch, bg="skyblue")
w.pack()

w.create_line(10, 635, 80, 610, fill="black", width= 15)
w.create_oval(30, 630, 60, 650, fill="brown")

target_x= 900

target_y= random.randrange(40, 610)
choice = simpledialog.askstring

w.create_oval(900, target_y, 900 -40, target_y -40, fill="pink")

while(True):
    if choice == "n":
        break;


    w.create_oval(900, target_y, 900 -40, target_y -40, fill="pink")     

    dMove= w.create_oval(81, 600, 80+10, 600+10, fill= "red")


    degree = simpledialog.askstring("Enter degree", "What is your guess",      
        initialvalue="Enter a degree")

    degree= 90 - int(degree)


    for i in range(90):
        w.move(dMove, math.sin(math.radians(degree))*10, \
            -math.cos(math.radians(degree))*10)
        time.sleep(0.06)
        w.update()

    b = 820
    a  =  target_y    


    c = b / math.cos(math.radians(degree))

    c1 = math.sqrt(math.pow(b, 2) + math.pow(target_y+10, 2)) 
    c2 = math.sqrt(math.pow(b, 2) + math.pow(target_y-10, 2))
    w.update()


    if c < c2 and c > c1:
         print("You got it")
         break
    else:
         print("enter degree")
```

Comment: you need to use timers

Comment: I dont think we learned this.

Comment: well theres no time like the present google can probably help you with this ... search for "animate movement pygame"

Comment: this is  more along the lines of calculating a triangle and determining whether the target was hit or not.

Comment: oh I see ... i thought this was animating the bullet movement ...

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Basically if you run the code, the bullet allows degrees to be entered through a dialog box, and it will shoot accordingly while generating a random target. problem is nothing happens once you shoot, it just asks for another degree to be entered to shoot again.

Comment: are you expecting a parabolic curve? or is this just a straight line?

Comment: straight line using degrees.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually computing, but I note that none of the code in your `c`/`c1`/`c2` calculations actually refers to `a` (or `target_y`). So there's no possible way that your current code checks if it hits properly, since it doesn't even look at the target's position.

Comment: would there be a way to make the c1/c2 refer to the target? i thought i did by having the math code in the c1/ c2 line?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what that code does. But it doesn't reference `a`, so it can't be anything relative to the target.

Comment: hold on sorry let me adjust the code to what it is now

Comment: the code as of now just shoots a bullet based off degrees, and then once its done, it asks to shoot again instead of saying whether or not it hit or missed the target

Answer (score 0):

The code keeps asking for a new `degrees` because it always thinks you miss the target. I have no idea how your current calculation of whether you hit or not is supposed to work, so I don't really know how to fix it directly. But I've come up with two new ways to make the thing function as intended.

There are two different approaches to collision detection that can work here. The first is to compute whether you hit or not directly from the angle, since nothing changes dynamically after you choose the angle to take the shot. Based on the position of the target, you can compute the angle that would hit the target dead center, and also compute the maximum offset from that angle that would still hit the target with at least part of the bullet. If the user enters an angle between `perfect_angle - max_offset` and `perfect_angle + max_offset`, it will be a hit.

```
from tkinter import*
import time
import math
import random

master = Tk()
cw= 1000
ch=650
w = Canvas(master, width=cw, height=ch, bg="skyblue")
w.pack()

w.create_line(10, 635, 80, 610, fill="black", width= 15)
w.create_oval(30, 630, 60, 650, fill="brown")

target_x= 900
target_y= random.randrange(40, 605)
target_radius = 20

bullet_x = 91
bullet_y = 605
bullet_radius = 10

rel_x = target_x - bullet_x
rel_y = target_y - bullet_y

perfect_angle = math.atan2(rel_y, rel_x)
distance = math.sqrt(rel_x**2 + rel_y**2)
max_angle_offset = math.asin((bullet_radius + target_radius)/ distance)

target = w.create_oval(target_x-target_radius, target_y-target_radius,
                       target_x+target_radius, target_y+target_radius,
                       fill="pink")

#print(math.degrees(perfect_angle), math.degrees(max_angle_offset))

while True:
    bullet = w.create_oval(bullet_x-bullet_radius, bullet_y-bullet_radius,
                           bullet_x+bullet_radius, bullet_y+bullet_radius,
                           fill= "red")

    degree = simpledialog.askstring("Enter degree", "What is your guess",      
        initialvalue="Enter a degree")

    rad = math.radians(-float(degree))


    for i in range(int(distance / 10) + 1):
        w.move(bullet, math.cos(rad)*10, math.sin(rad)*10)
        time.sleep(0.06)
        w.update()

    #print(math.degrees(rad), math.degrees(perfect_angle - rad))

    if perfect_angle - max_angle_offset <= rad <= perfect_angle + max_angle_offset:
         print("You got it")
         break
    else:
         print("enter degree")
```

The other approach to the problem is to do the collision detection while you're moving the bullet, rather than all up front. This will work much better for you if you later want to change the game to have a moving target, or if you change the bullet's dynamics to be less easily calculable in advance (e.g add drag). I simply extract the coordinates of our bullet from the `Canvas` (averaging the bounds to get the center), and do a distance check against the target. If on any given frame we're closer than the sum of the radii, we've hit! (I'm actually checking the distances squared in order to avoid a costly square root, but it works out the same way.)

```
from tkinter import*
import time
import math
import random

master = Tk()
cw= 1000
ch=650
w = Canvas(master, width=cw, height=ch, bg="skyblue")
w.pack()

w.create_line(10, 635, 80, 610, fill="black", width= 15)
w.create_oval(30, 630, 60, 650, fill="brown")

target_x= 900
target_y= random.randrange(40, 605)
target_radius = 20

bullet_x = 91
bullet_y = 605
bullet_radius = 10

rel_x = target_x - bullet_x
rel_y = target_y - bullet_y
distance = math.sqrt(rel_x**2 + rel_y**2)

hit_distance = bullet_radius + target_radius

target = w.create_oval(target_x-target_radius, target_y-target_radius,
                       target_x+target_radius, target_y+target_radius,
                       fill="pink")

hit = False

while True:
    bullet = w.create_oval(bullet_x-bullet_radius, bullet_y-bullet_radius,
                           bullet_x+bullet_radius, bullet_y+bullet_radius,
                           fill= "red")

    degree = simpledialog.askstring("Enter degree", "What is your guess",      
        initialvalue="Enter a degree")

    rad = math.radians(-float(degree))


    for i in range(int(distance / 10) + 1):
        w.move(bullet, math.cos(rad)*10, math.sin(rad)*10)
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = w.coords(bullet)
        x = (x1 + x0) // 2
        y = (y1 + y0) // 2
        if (target_x-x)**2 + (target_y-y)**2 < hit_distance**2:
            hit = True
        time.sleep(0.06)
        w.update()

    if hit:
         print("You got it")
         break
    else:
        #print(x, y, target_x, target_y,
        #      (target_x-x)**2 + (target_y-y)**2, hit_distance**2)
        print("enter degree")
```

Note, I've also cleaned up a lot of other stuff in the code, since it was impossible to tell where some of the constants you were using came from (and which of them might have been incorrect).

An especially important change is that the `target_x`/`_y` variables and the new `bullet_x`/`_y` variables always refer to the *center* of the object in question, which makes the math much easier. Your old code was offsetting the two shapes by their radii in different directions!

You were also using your `degrees` angle in a very odd way. I now convert it to radians just once and let it keep the normal mathematical meaning (angles start at zero along the positive x-axis and increase when rotating towards the positive y-axis). This means the angles the bullet takes are generally negative, but that doesn't trouble us, since we're not going to be displaying them (except in the debugging `print` calls I've left commented out).